# Converting a string to an Array of datetime x and y values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working with HighCharts and trying to update the chart series.
So far, everything works fine when I use;

```
chart.series[0].setData([Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,14,54,52), 34.74],[Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,15,24,52), 35.6]);
```

However, the real data comes as a string such as;

```
data = '[Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,14,54,52), 34.74]^[Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,15,24,52), 35.6]';
```

Since the setData() method requires an **Array of DateTime x and y values**, I have to convert the above string to an array, which might be simple but I can't really get it working...
I tried two ways:

1. using Array.from()

   v2 = '[Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,14,54,52), 34.74]^[Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,15,24,52), 35.6]';
   line = v2.split('^');
   data = Array.from(line);
2. using push()

   v2 = '[Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,14,54,52), 34.74]^[Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,15,24,52), 35.6]';
   line = v2.split('^');
   data = []
   data.push(line)

but neither ways worked for me...

Can please someone point me to the right way of getting the array from the string?

Thanks
Gus

Comment: Why does it come as a string? I would recommend rectifying the source rather than trying to parse the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 var result = "";
  var arrayOfDate = [];
  var data = '[Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,14,54,52), 34.74]^[Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,15,24,52), 35.6]';

 var array = data.split('^');

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 var arr = array[i].replace('[Date.UTC(','').replace(']','').replace(')','');

 var miniArray = arr.split(',');

 var dt = Date.UTC(miniArray[0], miniArray[1],miniArray[2],miniArray[3],miniArray[4],miniArray[5]);


  arrayOfDate.push(dt);
  arrayOfDate.push(miniArray[6]);
}

chart.series[0].setData([arrayOfDate[0], arrayOfDate[1]],[arrayOfDate[2], arrayOfDate[3]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

the line array is fine. You should define line first by using *var/let/const*.

```
const v2 = '[Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,14,54,52), 34.74]^[Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,15,24,52), 35.6]';

const  line = v2.split('^');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to change the data structure, you can modify it by JS and adapt it to Highcharts requirements. For example:

```
const data = '[Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,14,54,52), 34.74]^[Date.UTC(2022, 9, 29,15,24,52), 35.6]';
const splittedData = data.split('^');
const processedData = splittedData.map(dataEl => {
  const pureData = dataEl.replace('[Date.UTC(', '').replace(')', '').replace(']', '');
  const pureDataArr = pureData.split(',');
  const value = pureDataArr.pop();

  return [Date.UTC(...pureDataArr), +value];
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vsop81wL/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data